native support of passkey on Android
Got one quick tech point to confirm with you around passkey.
If any android app DOES NOT want to use any full-browser OR custom-tab OR even embedded-web-view to complete passkey-authentication, can the app directly call the platform-API to run the fido-authentication or fido-registration ceremony.
If app can, then would you please show me that Android-API that app can incorporate in its code ??
Thanks.

Yes, you can find all of this information on passkeys.dev (https://passkeys.dev/docs/reference/android/)
